# Exibindo Video em Flash no Android 2.3?

Tags: java, android

Bom já tentei de todos os modos rodar vídeo em flash no android 2.3 do 4.0 pra frente vai fácil a partir de um webview.Procurando no google e em alguns fóruns vi pessoas montando através de VideoView. Pra mim não deu certo.

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("http://www.ustream.tv/channel/5474055");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

Bom se alguém tiver alguma dica. Detalhe eu não quero ter baixar o flash e instalar. Assim deu mas, queria algo nativo ou sem a necessidade de baixar algo.
Bom vou deixar uma print do erro quando tento dar load da url no android 2.3 a mesma url carrega tudo normal do android 4.0 pra cima.

[image: Erro Carregando url flash em um webView android 2.3]

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta na linha 104 da classe AoVivo, no metodo onCreate().
La voce usa a função setLayerType, que só foi adicionada na API 11. Então, antes de usá-la, voce deve checar a versão do dispositivo, desse jeito:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
    // Coloque a chamada da funcao setLayerType aqui dentro
}
```